# Batch update participants by profile - show more than 9 fields

Tags: civievent, profile, search, batches

I'd be grateful if anyone knows the answer to this:

I need to make a variety of batch update profiles that allow me to edit details of up to 40 custom participant fields on one screen. The batch update by profile is perfect for this.

However, while I can make these profiles exactly as I want them, when I use them for 'Batch update participants by profile' only the first 9 fields are shown on the batch update screen. I've tried this with a variety of different profiles, with different custom fields from different custom field sets and get the same result - only the first 9 fields show. This is also the case regardless of whether I am showing 4 or 22 rows. (My 2 test scenarios).

Is there a way to change this from 9 to 40 columns?

I'm on Civi 4.6.12, Drupal 7.43. We've long ago changed our php input variable limit to 4000 because we have many many blocks in our site, so it can't be this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try increase $_maxFields in:
CRM/Event/Form/Task/Batch.php

> /**    * Maximum profile fields that will be displayed.    */
>   protected $_maxFields = 9;

This would be a core hack though! To do this properly -> copy Batch.php -> into a custom_php directory.

Comment: Perfect! Adding this an override php file has worked exactly. 

Is there any reason the default is set to 9 fields? This seems rather small to me, and so I wonder if there are performance or reliability issues that one should know about if setting it to a number like 40. - apart from the obvious multiplication of variables - 100 rows of 40 fields is 4000 variables!

Comment: Yes 4000 is a lot! The =9 is conservative; =40 is a lot! You may have to make that 2 batch edit profiles (updating 20 each); and/or update fewer contacts per batch (eg 50 instead of 100); You'll find out quickly if there are performance issues; adjust accordingly!

Comment: @Andyg8: please don't forget to accept the answer - so stackexhange will know this one is dealt with!

Comment: See this pending improvement [CRM-20921
Move hard-coded CONST limits to settings](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20921)