# How to make tables with fixed header and left column - scroll vertically and horizontally

Tags: civievent, search-results

In our use case we need to batch update participants with large tables - up to 45 columns and 20-50 rows. For this to have any hope of success we had to find a way of getting the table to scroll vertically and horizontally, while fixing the header and left column. How to do it? Read on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found a way that may perhaps be helpful for others, so we're posting the answer here. This applies to Drupal 7, Civi 4.6.17:

1. We needed to add extra fields to the Batch update profile code, as per [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11689/batch-update-participants-by-profile-show-more-than-9-fields).
2. We used some javascript and custom css and allocated it to our batch update pages as a Drupal block, using php to target pages with '_qf_Batch_display' in their query string. (Actually, the Css went in our custom css file.)
3. You can find a simplified example containing the javascript, html and css [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/).

Hope this might give others a leg up to a system that has worked really well for us.